# Why file full permission mode is different than for directories?

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I read in `Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible by Richard Blum Christine Bresnahan` that :

> The umask value is subtracted from the full permission set for an object. **The full permission
>   for a file is mode 666, but for a directory it’s 777**.

So if a file can't be have read, write, execute permissions at once, does a user have to change file everytime he needs to perform an action. What should a programmer do if he needs to test his code?
And what about other file types?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you misunderstand.  files can be executable.

Comment: Sure, but I think files can't have all 3 permissions at once .

Comment: you still misunderstand.  they can.   this is something you can easily test yourself: `touch file ; chmod 777 file; ls -l file`

Comment: Yes thank you. But what does the author mean by `The full permission for a file is mode 666, but for a directory it’s 777.` Can you please explain it to me. I'm a little confused now.

Comment: i haven't read that book, but it looks to me as if the author is talking specifically about  how the `umask` setting affects permissions when a file or directory is created.

Comment: The below answers cover your question already, however in addition: if you would like to edit the default mask for users, you can edit `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc` to affect all users on the system, or edit the a specific user’s `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` by adding the line `unmask 027` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The umask value is subtracted from the full permission set for an object.

This isn't true. Or at least it's inaccurate and simplified to a common case.

- First, the base value is *not* "the full set of permissions", but instead whatever the process creating the file sets as the file permissions. Granted, for regular files, this is usually `0666`: the idea being that (say) a text editor shouldn't decide what the permissions of a file should be, but the user should be allowed to decide it via the `umask`.

  But a process creating the file doesn't need to use `0666` as the file permissions. For private files (think SSH keys), `0600` would be used, so that regardless of the umask, the file is never accessible by others than the owner.
  Also, for executable files, `0777` could be used so that the resulting file is executable.

  For directories, `0777` would be common, since the `x` bit is practically as necessary as the `r` bit for general use. For general data files, it isn't, so this is why the common case is `0666` for files, and `0777` for directories.

  The base permissions used could of course be something else, but those are likely to be the common cases.
- Second, the value of the umask is not *subtracted*, but masked out. Subtraction implies a carry from one bit to the next up, and subtracting e.g. the `0007` from `0666` would result in `0657`. That's not how the umask works, and that would not be useful.

Note that the umask is only used when a file is *created*, [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) also calls it the "file mode creation mask". After that, `chmod()` can be used to change the permissions without being limited by the umask.

> So if a file can't be have read, write, execute permissions at once,

Sure, they can. It's just not useful for nonexecutable files.

Answer (score 1):

Because by default files are not executable, while directories are.

- The "execute" flag on a directory lets you open files that are in it, so is necessary in most cases (the "read" flag lets you list the directory contents, but not open the files in it).
- The "execute" flag in a regular file makes it executable, and this isn't generally wanted.